# How to create a function in SQL Server that returns bit

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a function that verifies if the current version of an application is the last version which exists in the database. This function has to retrieve 0 or 1. 
This is what i tried so far but it's giving Msg 102, Incorrect syntax near 'return'. How to make this work?

```
create function isLastVersion(
     @currentVersion nvarchar(10),
     @appCode nvarchar(128),
     @serial nvarchar(128))
returns bit
as 
begin
    declare @ret bit
    select @ret = case 
when @currentVersion = (select *from getAppLastVersion(@appCode,@serial)) 
then 1 else 0
    return @ret
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing `end` on your `case`;

```
select @ret = case when @currentVersion = (select *from getAppLastVersion(@appCode,@serial)) 
              then 1 else 0 END
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now i want to call this function, but it gives me another error: 'isLastVersion' is not a recognized built-in function name. And i can't find where this function is stored.

Comment: include the schema, usually dbo, when you call the function.